# How to Scale GUI in Cube World?

Tags: cube-world

I have had Cube World for a while now and I am wondering if there is a way to scale the GUI outside of the game. I realize Wollay will be adding this soon, but it gets really annoying seeing chat where my crafting should be.

I have gone in to the location I installed Cube World, and it has a file: GUI.plx
I'm guessing I could modify the file in some way to scale the GUI, but I will need a program allowing me to get in the file. If I can't do it that way, is there any other way?

Comment: Try opening it in Notepad, and see what happens.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Will do.

Comment: @MichaelFrank I tried this but, as the answer below, .plx files are  Plasma files so it was just a bunch of code. All I can do is wait it out. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the next cube world [update](https://picroma.com/blog/post/11) will have scalable UI as part of it, your best bet is probably just waiting it out, as .plx is a file extension that only wollay can mess with as they are made using PLasma.. his own graphics engine.

Comment: Hmn, as far as the .plx thanks, but, I was reading on the forums and it said there was now scalable GUI. Maybe it was false :P